# How to remove MetaStream 3 Plugin for Firefox

Tags: windows, windows-xp, firefox, plugins

I just reformatted a machine, and installed Firefox 3.6.8, now when I use Firefox I get a message that says:

> "Firefox has determined that the following add-ons are known to cause stability or security problems."

I've gotten this message at least three times now, I think that is because Firefox has disabled it for 3 different user accunts on this windows-xp machine, I can't remember if I've gotten the message more than once for the same account or not.. but regardless of that I'd like to remove this plug-in, because I have no idea what it's for and since it'll be disabled then why do I need it around for?

I've done some google searching on how to remove this, but all I find are articles about why Firefox automatically disables it, I can't seem to find anything on how to remove it..

Does anyone have any idea how to remove this junk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1761105), you should remove Viewpoint Media Player through Add/Remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

Removing Viewpoint Media Player via Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel enables one to then remove the MetaStream plugin. Viewpoint Media Player is not a useful program (please contradict me on this point if you know better). Adobe Flash Player, which is free to and easy to download, is useful. Out with the bad in with the good.

Answer (score -2):

I removed the Media Stream 3 plugin by going to

Start > Computer > C Drive > Program Files (x86)

Find the file named View Point and delete it. Now it is gone from Firefox plugins.